# Fade in pause for a sec and fade out a span only JS CSS HTML

Tags: javascript, html, css, fadein, fadeout

hey i try to fade in pause for a sec and fade out a span , im using class add and remove through timeout and interval . i cant figure it out  someone can help?
i tried to  do it with active class but i didnt make it .
i searched for it on google and found nothing with JS only Jquery that i dont want to use ATM
--------HTML----

```
<div class="desgin">
       <div class="im__desgin"><h1>I'm Desgin.</h1></div>
       <div class="what__design">
         <span class="design-kinds ">WebSite's</span>
         <span class="design-kinds">Logos</span>
         <span class="design-kinds">Brands</span>
       </div>
    </div>
```

-----CSS-----

```
.desgin {
  font-size: 40px;
  /* color: aliceblue; */
  color: #000;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: space-between;
  padding: 40px 150px;
  position: relative;
  float: left;
}

.what__design {
  font-size: 8rem;
  align-items: center;
  float: left;
  opacity: 1;
  position: relative;
}

.design-kinds {
  opacity: 0;
  visibility: hidden;
  position: absolute;
}

/* .design-kinds.active {
  opacity: 1;
  visibility: visible;
  animation: fade 3s ease-in-out 3s 1;
} */

.design-kinds.fadein {
  animation: fadeIn 1s ease-in;
  visibility: visible;
}
.design-kinds.fadeout {
  animation: fadeOut 1s ease-out;
  visibility: hidden;
}

@keyframes fadeIn {
  0% {
    opacity: 0;
  }
  100% {
    opacity: 100;
  }
}

@keyframes fadeOut {
  0% {
    opacity: 100;
  }
  100% {
    opacity: 0;
  }
}
```

---JS---

```
const changeText = document.querySelector(".what__design");
const textToShow = document.querySelectorAll(".design-kinds");

//Fade in  First span and fade out Last span
let index = 0;
let doneOrNot = "not";
function showText() {
  const spans = [...textToShow];
  if (index === spans.length - 1) {
    index = 0;
  }
  if (doneOrNot === "done") {
    doneOrNot = "not";
    setTimeout(() => {
      spans[index].classList.remove("fadein");
      spans[index].classList.add("fadeout");
    }, 4000);
    index++;
    console.log(doneOrNot);
  }
  if (doneOrNot === "not") {
    spans[index].classList.add("fadein");
    doneOrNot = "done";
    console.log(doneOrNot);
  }
}

setInterval(showText, 4000);
```

THANKS <3

Comment: Could you explain a bit more what it is that would trigger the fading in and out, or is it continuous, and is it all the spans?

Comment: i try to do what this website have look at this  
https://ballsymedia.co.uk/

Answer (score 0):

If you want to animate it for a single time, than you don't want to need javascript.

```css
.desgin {
  font-size: 40px;
  /* color: aliceblue; */
  color: #000;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: space-between;
  padding: 40px 150px;
  position: relative;
  float: left;
}

.what__design {
  font-size: 8rem;
  align-items: center;
  float: left;
  opacity: 1;
  position: relative;
}

.design-kinds {
  position: absolute;
}

.web{
    animation: animate1 4s 2s 1 ease-in-out ;
    color: black;
    opacity: 0;
}
.logo{
        animation: animate1 4s 8s 1 ease-in-out ;
    opacity: 0;
}
.brand{
        animation: animate1 4s 14s 1 ease-in-out ;
    opacity: 0;
}
@keyframes animate1{
    0%,100%{
        opacity: 0;
    }
    50%{
        opacity: 10;
    }
}
@keyframes animate2{
    0%,100%{
        opacity: 0;
    }
    50%{
        opacity: 10;
    }
}
@keyframes animate3{
    0%,100%{
        opacity: 0;
    }
    50%{
        opacity: 10;
    }
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
    <title>Document</title>
</head>
<body>
<div class="desgin">
       <div class="im__desgin"><h1>I'm Desgin.</h1></div>
       <div class="what__design">
         <span class="design-kinds web">WebSite's</span>
         <span class="design-kinds logo">Logos</span>
         <span class="design-kinds brand">Brands</span>
       </div>
    </div>
    <!-- <script src="index.js"></script> -->
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: but i want it to work none stop until the web is stopped,how can i do that?, i actually manage to do that with Jquery .

but still want to know the logic without

Answer (score 0):

The given JS checks whether done is set, if it is immediately sets it to not and then checks if it's not and acts on that. This probably needs changing to an if...else combination.

Although you can do the animation by JS you may like to consider doing it with CSS as that should optimise the system's use of for example the GPU as you are only changing an animatable property (opacity).

While the specific example given here could be done entirely by CSS - setting up one set of keyframes which fade in, pause and fadeout a text for 33.3333% of the total animation time of 3*whatever seconds you choose - to be more general it adds a bit of JS which is run just once at the start to set up the keyframes to give the right %s however many texts there are.

This is done by setting CSS variables which are used in CSS calcs to give the overall animation time and the delay times - each text starts its animation offset depending on its index and then it runs forever.

```html
<head>
  <style>
    .desgin {
      font-size: 40px;
      /* color: aliceblue; */
      color: #000;
      align-items: center;
      justify-content: space-between;
      padding: 40px 150px;
      position: relative;
      float: left;
    }
    
    .what__design {
      font-size: 8rem;
      align-items: center;
      float: left;
      opacity: 1;
      position: relative;
    }
    
    .design-kinds {
      opacity: 0;
      /*visibility: hidden;*/
      position: absolute;
      animation: fadeInOut calc(var(--num) * var(--t)) infinite linear;
      animation-delay: calc(var(--n) * var(--t));
      animation-fill-mode: forwards;
    }
  </style>
  <style id="keyframes">

  </style>
</head>

<body>
  div class="desgin">
  <div class="im__desgin">
    <h1>I'm Desgin.</h1>
  </div>
  <div class="what__design">
    <span class="design-kinds ">WebSite's</span>
    <span class="design-kinds">Logos</span>
    <span class="design-kinds">Brands</span>
  </div>
  </div>
  <script>
    const showFor = 6; // set this to the number of seconds each text takes to fade in, pause for 1 second and fade out again

    const whatDesign = document.querySelector('.what__design');
    const designKinds = document.querySelectorAll('.design-kinds');
    const len = designKinds.length;

    whatDesign.style.setProperty('--num', len);
    whatDesign.style.setProperty('--t', showFor + 's');

    for (let n = 0; n < len; n++) {
      designKinds[n].style.setProperty('--n', n);
    }

    const pcEachGets = 100 / len; // the percentage of total cycle time each bit of text gets
    const pcForOneSecond = pcEachGets / showFor; // the % of total cycle time that equals 1 second - 1 second is the required pause time
    const pcFadeInOrOut = (pcEachGets - pcForOneSecond) / 2;
    document.querySelector('#keyframes').innerHTML = `@keyframes fadeInOut {
  0% {
    opacity: 0;   
  }
  ` + pcFadeInOrOut + `% {
    opacity: 1;
  }
  ` + (pcFadeInOrOut + pcForOneSecond) + `% {
    opacity: 1;
  }
  ` + pcEachGets + `% {
    opacity: 0;
  }
  100% {
    opacity: 0;
  }
}`;
  </script>
</body>
```

Comment: wow that actually work !
but why did u do a style with the id of keyframes in the html files ?

and i realy try to understand what u have done but  so hard !

Comment: All that is happening is that the JS is setting up the keyframes which get a text to fade in for a percentage, stay for a second then fade out for a percentage, then stay faded out while the other texts have a go. It has to write the keyframes in a style element, they cannot be inline.

Answer (score 0):

I think this will help you.
if you want this animation as a infinite loop.

```js
const changeText = document.querySelector(".what__design");
const textToShow = document.querySelectorAll(".design-kinds");

//Fade in  First span and fade out Last span
let index = 0;

function showText() {
    setInterval(() => {


        if (index < 2) {
            textToShow[index].classList.add("fadeinOut");
            index++;
        }
        else {
            textToShow[index].classList.add("fadeinOut");
            setTimeout(() => {
                textToShow[2].classList.remove("fadeinOut");
            }, 4000);
            index = 0;
        }
        if (index > 0) {
            setTimeout(() => {
                textToShow[index - 1].classList.remove("fadeinOut");
            }, 4000);
        }

    }, 5000);
}
showText();
```

```css
.desgin {
    font-size: 40px;
    /* color: aliceblue; */
    color: #000;
    align-items: center;
    justify-content: space-between;
    padding: 40px 150px;
    position: relative;
    float: left;
  }
  
  .what__design {
    font-size: 8rem;
    align-items: center;
    float: left;
    opacity: 1;
    position: relative;
  }
  
  .design-kinds {
    opacity: 0;
    visibility: hidden;
    position: absolute;
  }
  
  /* .design-kinds.active {
    opacity: 1;
    visibility: visible;
    animation: fade 3s ease-in-out 3s 1;
  } */
  
  .design-kinds.fadeinOut {
    animation: fadeInOut 4s ease-in;
    visibility: visible;
  }
  
  @keyframes fadeInOut {
    0%,100% {
      opacity: 0;
    }
    20%,80% {
      opacity: 100;
    }
  
  }
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
    <title>Document</title>
</head>
<body>
    <div class="desgin">
        <div class="im__desgin"><h1>I'm Desgin.</h1></div>
        <div class="what__design">
          <span class="design-kinds ">WebSite's</span>
          <span class="design-kinds">Logos</span>
          <span class="design-kinds">Brands</span>
        </div>
     </div>
    <script src="index.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

I figure some out but still i have a delay that i doest succeed to manage the delay after the function is done

```
        <div class="im__desgin"><h1>I Desgin.</h1></div>
        <div class="what__design">
          <span class="design-kinds" id="Kind-1">WebSite's</span>
          <span class="design-kinds" id="Kind-2">Logos</span>
          <span class="design-kinds" id="Kind-3">Brands</span>
        </div>
     </div>
```

```
.desgin {
  text-align: center;
  font-size: 40px;
  color: aliceblue;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: space-between;
  padding: 40px 150px;
  position: relative;
  float: left;
}

.what__design {
  font-size: 8rem;
  align-items: center;
  float: left;
  position: relative;
}

.design-kinds {
  text-align: center;

  opacity: 0;
  position: absolute;
}

.effect {
  animation: animate1 4s 2s 1 ease-in-out;
  transform: scale(0.5);
  opacity: 0;
}

@keyframes animate1 {
  0%,
  100% {
    transform: scale(0.5);
    opacity: 0;
  }
  30%,
  50% {
    transform: scale(1);
    opacity: 10;
  }
  30% {
    transform: scale(1);
    opacity: 10;
  }
}
```

```
const spans = document.querySelectorAll(".design-kinds");
//call function before page load
showText();
//Changing Text

function showText() {
  //Kind --1--
  $("#Kind-1").addClass("effect");
  setTimeout(() => {
    $("#Kind-1").removeClass("effect");
  }, 6000);
  //Kind --2--
  setTimeout(() => {
    $("#Kind-2").addClass("effect");
  }, 3700);
  setTimeout(() => {
    $("#Kind-2").removeClass("effect");
  }, 9800);
  //Kind --3--
  setTimeout(() => {
    $("#Kind-3").addClass("effect");
  }, 7700);
  setTimeout(() => {
    $("#Kind-3").removeClass("effect");
  }, 14000);
  
}

setInterval(showText, 13000);
```